# Getting ClassNotFoundException when receiving serialized object over socket

Tags: java, sockets, ipc, classnotfoundexception

First and foremost, the object I'm using (Book) should be fine:

```
public class Book implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String  name;
    private String  publisher;
    private int     numbOfPages;
    private int     id;
```

And both server and client have it (copy paste, no ulterior modification). So that is definitely not it.

Server:

```
ArrayList<Book> library = this.sql_db.getAllBooks();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
                this.client.getOutputStream());
        objOut.writeObject(library);
        objOut.flush();
    }
```

Client:

```
ArrayList<Book> library = new ArrayList<Book>();

    try {
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(Client.socket.getInputStream());
        //library = (ArrayList<Book>) objIn.readObject(); // This is where the stack trace is pointing to
        Object o = objIn.readObject(); // well actually here, since I commented last line and added this.
    }
```

Again, book is the same in both programs and is in the same package.

Stack trace points to my commented text, but just in case, here it is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: db.Book
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at client.Client.requestAllBooks(Client.java:39)
at handler.HandleUserRequest.<init>(HandleUserRequest.java:19)
at run.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: What's at line 39 in `Client` class

Comment: Like I said, my commented line. Object o (before that, the array list 'library')

Comment: so is `db.Book.class` in your clients classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The class must be present on the receiver's CLASSPATH. Serialization doesn't do that for you.